# How do theories of inflection account for syntactic expressions of a grammatical category?

Tags: morphology, morphosyntax

If an inflectional paradigm is as Gregory Stump describes in his 2015 book Inflectional Paradigms: a complete set of a lexeme L's cells, where a cell is a "pairing [of] the lexical content of L and the morphosyntactic content of σ with the word form w ... 〈L, σ : w〉"

Then the inflectional paradigm of the English lexeme **good** under degree of comparison could be

{ 〈**good**, {positive} : *good*〉,〈**good**, {comparative} : *better*〉,〈**good**, {superlative} : *best*〉}

For many adjectives it would be something with the *-er* and *-est* suffixes:

{ 〈**dark**, {positive} : *dark*〉,〈**dark**, {comparative} : *darker*〉,〈**dark**, {superlative} : *darkest*〉}

Yet a lot of adjectives cannot be inflected according to the grammatical category 'degree of comparison': **amazinger*, **affordablest*. Instead extra words have to be used, so the category must be expressed syntactically rather than inflectionally: *more amazing*, *most affordable*.

What would the inflectional paradigms of such words look like? It's not that the pairing of the lexeme **affordable** with the set of morphosyntactic properties {superlative} has no realisation at all, but that it's a periphrastic rather than inflectional realisation.

What would inflectional paradigm theories of morphology or other interesting (in this case) theories of morphology say is going on here?